# Spinner and HTML select

Tags: android

I have spinner for displaying categories. `((String)categorySpinner.getSelectedItem()))` gives the category name.

The spinner is initialized as given below:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < category.length; i++) {

    list.add(category[i].getName());
}

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
);
shoppingItemCategorySpnr.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Is there any idea to make spinner like HTML select-tag so that I can display category name and get category id?

Comment: Do you want something like spinner.getSelectedId() ?

Comment: @greenapps like `((MyCategory)spinner.getselectedItemObj()).getId()`

Comment: Isn't it enough that you take the name and determine the Id from the original list?

Comment: @greenapps that is possible. But `...getId()` will be simpler.

Comment: I wonder now what you mean by id? The position in the list?

Comment: spinner.getSelectedItem()
 spinner.getSelectedItemId()
 spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() Not usable?

Comment: @greenapps id is one data like name.